# Angular Lifecyclehook ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, lifecycle-hook

I want to update a variable each time after it changes in angular view.

How can it be achieved in angular without using `@input` decorator?

Comment: Have you tried ngOnChanges event?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code?

Comment: I have tried but it wont updated.But i haven't used @input decorator.

Comment: Why not use [`ngModelChange`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel) with a `ngModel` binding for whatever input you are having.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is called `title` in your component then you can do this:

```
  this.title.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe (newValue => {
        // do something based on the newvalue 
    });
```

However, you now have a subscriber that will fire every time the title changes. So you should really destroy it at some point, or you will get memory leak/stack overflow eg:

```
this.title.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .takeUntil(this.destroyValueChanges$)
      .subscribe (newValue => {
        // do something based on the newvalue 
    });
```

Delcare `destroyValueChanges$` as a `Subject` property of your component and in `ngOnDestroy` call `destroyValueChanges$.next();`

**NOTE**

Since you did not post any code, I have to guess what you are asking. I am assuming that title is an `<input>` on your template, in which the user is typing and hence that is how the value is changing. If the variable you are talking about is being changed 'outside' your component, then it needs to be have an @Input decorator and you need to use the ngOnChanges life-cycle hook.